# Scroll wheel vs. Explicit Scroll Buttons (OR BOTH!)

Tags: buttons, scrolling

Let's say you have a section of scrollable content, a lesson plan for example. It's contained in a sidebar in the UI. Assuming users understand that they can scroll with their scroll wheel or mousepad do you think it's also necessary to include explicit "scroll up" and "scroll down" buttons?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to see how that section looks to provide a relevant suggestion.

Comment: Would this be different to the browser's scrollbar? Do you mean to prevent it showing and provide your own scroll indicator?

Comment: Good point! Here is an example of the scrolling section (attached to the original post) - here I'm showing the scrollbar, making it present at all times to indicate there is more content is an option.

Answer (score 1):

i would say it isn't necessary to include such buttons.

Scrolling is common behaviour. So regardless if your user are using a mouse or scroll wheel, they would know how to scroll. a rare exception would be if you are catering to an older audience that aren't so tech savvy.

Also do make sure your content gives the affordance that there is more content below the fold, as sometimes users might assume its the end of the content if there's a paragraph ending just over the fold and there's no sign of anything else below for instance.